# Can an Actual Cognizance Crystal be used as Reality Revision's Material Component?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, psionics

From Reality Revision:

> Manifesting reality revision requires channeling psionic power through specially-treated crystals similar to cognizance crystals that cost 25,000 gp.

Does "same" overpower "similar", can an actual [Cognizance Crystal](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/psionics-unleashed/equipment/psionic-items/cognizance-crystals) be used as the material component?

The reason I ask is that if the psion has the feat [Craft Cognizance Crystal](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/psionics-unleashed/feats/craft-cognizance-crystal-item-creation/) they can use the feat, 25 days of their time, and pay the crafting cost (half the final value) to produce a 25,000gp cognizance crystal.

Comment: Question edited to remove follow on part about crystal values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### No, it cannot

The wording there is very specific, but instead of creating a new item and giving it a name and taking page space, they left it vague so the GM can come up with something *or* handwave a generic crystal *similar* to the one that already exists.

> specially-treated crystals

But if *Cognizance Crystals* were allowed, the wording would be different. Authors usually use the wording *"such as"* to denote examples of items they are talking about. So the wording here would have to be something similar to:

> specially-treated crystals, such as cognizance crystals, that cost 25,000 gp.

Comment: If the "specially treated crystals" are similar to Cognizance Crystals with no further explanation on what "specially treated" actually means then where is the "Craft Reality Revision Crystal" feat which would provide a similar process? (mostly rhetorical question there) Paizo dropped the ball and the DM is forced to pick it up... nothing abnormal I suppose, just a little disappointing.

Comment: You mean *Dreamscarred Press*. Paizo did not develop those rules.

Comment: And there is no surprise here. It is supposed to be like a wish, which not something cheap.