# Are expensive material component costs too specific?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, pricing, economy, special-materials

[Reality Revision](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/psionics-unleashed/psionic-powers/r/reality-revision/) requires a crystal worth 25,000 gp.
[Wish](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/w/wish/) requires a diamond worth 25,000 gp.
"[Grand Jewels](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/#TOC-Building-a-Treasure-Hoard)" in the treasure tables peak at 5,000 gp.

Perhaps there is a work around for [Reality Revision](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/psionics-unleashed/psionic-powers/r/reality-revision/) if a [Cognizance Crystal](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/psionics-unleashed/equipment/psionic-items/cognizance-crystals/) can be used as the material component (see linked [question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/141156/can-an-actual-cognizance-crystal-be-used-as-reality-revisions-material-componen)) as [Craft Cognizance Crystal](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/psionics-unleashed/feats/craft-cognizance-crystal-item-creation/) allows the use of 12,500 gp of "raw materials" to create a 25,000gp crystal over 25 days of crafting. "Raw materials" have no meaningful rarity so it's just a matter of having the funds. All good there... maybe.

So, now to [Wish](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/w/wish/)... a diamond is specifically cited as the expensive material component. It's not diamonds plural, it is a single diamond. The most expensive diamond you can find in treasure is worth 5,000 gp. A 25,000 gp diamond is so rare it doesn't even warrant a mention in random treasure tables.

To put the rarity in focus, even in a [metropolis](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/other-rules/kingdom-building/settlements/) there is only a 75% chance of finding a magic item of up to 16,000 gp value. The maximum spell level for a metropolis is 8th, so no wish casting even in the biggest population centres listed.

**How does someone procure one of these unmentionably rare 25,000 gp diamonds? And if using it for a Wish spell destroys it, how are there any left in a world with any wish casters in it?**

It isn't a feasible material component when it is so specific!
The wizard has clawed his/her way up 17 levels, scrimped 25,000 gp, and then is blocked by the rarity of the material component.
Sure, make it cost a lot, but let it be practical to source the materials without becoming BFFs with [Dumathoin](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Dumathoin) (or whatever god of gems your setting has handy).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### The [rules for grand jewels](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/#TOC-Building-a-Treasure-Hoard) don't peak their value at 5,000 gp.

> Grand Jewels (5,000 gp **or more**): clearest bright green emerald; diamond; jacinth; ruby

Grand jewels can be worth more than 5,000gp, instead of setting a cap on them the rules do the opposite and set a minimum. The lowest value diamond you can find is 5,000 gp.

Comment: Good catch, I missed the significance of "or more". Still, how rare are 25,000 gp grand jewels given the settlement demographics? (Oh gods, is that a separate question too?)

Comment: @niekell you guessed it

Comment: [Settlements](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/other-rules/kingdom-building/settlements/) seem to only restrict magic items purchases however.

Comment: Now I wonder if there's a gem worth more than 5,000 gp in a published-by-Paizo adventure. That is, one that can be discovered *without* murdering a spellcaster and looting his material components.

Comment: Yes, there is. By the way, the 16k base value is just the *base*, it starts there and then is modified by settlement qualities. The City of Brass has a base value os 29k gp.

Answer (score 17):

Use Fabricate to convert 5 5,000gp diamonds into a single one with a 25,000gp value?

From my reading of the *Fabricate* spell, the caster converts "material of one sort (which in this case would be a pile of diamonds with a **total** value of 25kgp) into a (single) product that is of the same material" & since the "quality of items made by this spell is commensurate with the quality of material used", the value of the individual gems should be retained allowing for a single 25kgp gem to be produced. Even the most expensive 5kgp diamonds would be small enough for 5 of them to fit in a single cubic foot of space (though if you can't find five of those, use 25 1kgp diamonds - the spell doesn't care) & the finished product isn't going to be used for anything other than as a spell component, so crafting isn't an issue.

Logically, it should work (& only needs a 5th level spell to do it too!).

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: Even within the realm of D&D economics I'm not sure this logic follows. Fabricate lets you do things like turn a pile of logs into a table. The rules you've quoted don't imply that the table must be the same value as the logs, just that the quality of the table must line up with the quality of the logs used. However, the table is still clearly more valuable than the logs, as evidenced by the existence of table makers. Since fabricate _can_ influence price, it may make sense to let PCs use it to increase the value of diamonds by influencing e.g. the diamond's cut. But, you probably shouldn't...

Comment: @Sardonic raises a good point, that might simplify @Ian's answer.  In the real world, diamond values do not scale linearly with diamond weights -- an uncut diamond might be cut into a single gem worth $10k, or two gems worth $4k each.  (Note the word `might`.)  However I don't expect a typical GM to be up on their gemology.

Comment: @CodeswithHammer Do gems need to be cut to be used for a material component? I think you can just maximize the most valuable cut (or lack thereof!) using Fabricate. Great thought, Ian.

Comment: @MichaelW.: That gets into parsing "quality of the material" and "quality of the item".  Is an uncut gem-quality mineral the same quality as a cut gemstone?  This is the sort of question that most GMs don't get paid enough to properly answer.

Comment: @Codes with Hammer True; a gem in reality generally has a far higher price twice that 2 half it's mass, but in a world where any 9th+ level wizard could bond items together, this would no longer apply. There would be a premium for larger diamonds (the services of spellcasters aren't cheap) & the crafting of a cut gem would still require a skilled individual (who also wouldn't be cheap), but the intrinsic value of gems would wind up more in line with that of gold; easily melted & a fine piece has greater value than a lump of raw metal due to the skill required, but with prices based on mass.

Answer (score 8):

> how are there any left in a world with any wish casters in it?

Fantasy worlds are invented for our convenience, so they aren’t necessarily constrained by economics, and don’t contain independed people.

**Look beyond the game at the metagame.**

Having specific and expensive material components is a way for the GM to gate access to these specific PC and NPC abilities. The world has 25,000gp diamonds in exactly the locations and quantities that the Game Master decides.

Some GMs will make 25,000gp diamonds as common as glass because they want their players to have easy access to these abilities. Other GMs may make them rare and precious so that players *can* use the ability but will go to great lengths to find another way. Still other GMs will use these as McGuffins for adventures - "The only source of such perfect diamonds is in the Lost Mine of Eee, which is, you know, lost. Oh, and infested with demons. And a wizard that can cast Wish."

GMs don’t have to use random generation for significant treasures. One randomly generated Staff of the Magi given to a 4th level wizard tends to teach that lesson.

Answer (score 4):

> And if using it for a Wish spell destroys it, how are there any left in a world with any wish casters in it?

A couple of things to think about:

- There aren't that many casters capable of casting *Wish*. Sure, it seems relatively easy for a PC to climb to that level, but PCs are special, and NPCs with power that high tend to be legendary figures that have left their mark on history. A (humanoid) *Wish* caster is a household name.
- If you're capable of casting Wish, you're *more* than capable of traveling to the Plane of Earth, where gems are far more common (and larger).

Answer (score 1):

> And if using it for a Wish spell destroys it, how are there any left
>   in a world with any wish casters in it?

It becomes an adventure hook.

- The characters can go get it before some evil wizard uses it for
  their nefarious plot.
- The characters can (as @MichaelW. mentions) go to the plane of Earth
  to find/min/buy one.
- The characters can go to the City of Brass and bargain for one (no
  downside there....).
- The characters can do a big favor for one of their gods and get it as
  a reward.
- My favorite: the characters receive one before they are able to cast
  that spell and have to try to hide/sell/trade it before someone
  strong enough to cast a Wish spell comes looking for it.